# what is the best way to found memory leaks in windows form application?

Tags: c#, memory-leaks, bindingsource

I am using windows form application with binding source. I have initialized the binding source as below code in form InitializeComponenet() method. Can I know the below code is correct?

```
private System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource bindingSource1;
private void InitializeComponent()
{
this.bindingSource1 = new System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource(this.components);;
((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.bindingSource1)).BeginInit();
this.SuspendLayout();
this.bindingSource1.DataSource = typeof(WindowsFormsApplication2.Class1);

control.DataSource = this.bindingSource1;
((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.bindingSource1)).EndInit();
this.ResumeLayout(false);
}
```

When making any changes in designer, then run the sample, the visual studio goes to Not Responding state. So I suspect some memory leak problem in the control, so how can i found the memory leak problem or visual studio not responding problem?

Comment: "Not Responding" has nothing to do with Memory Leaks.

Answer (score 0):

Using a memory profiler. Simple as that. VS has one. And then there is always memprofiler.

This is about the only way to find a memory leak and analyze it.